# Animating on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How can I make `hover()` run continuously? I'd like that when I mouse over `#up_btn`, the `top` property keeps animating. Right now, it only runs once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up_btn").hover(function(){
        var new_num = parseInt($("#move_box").css("top"));
        $("#move_box").css("top", new_num + 1);
    })
})
```

Comment: please add in the HTML of your page.

Comment: ProTip™: You don't have to use `parseInt` on `top` with jQuery. Just do `.css('top', '+= 1')`!

Comment: @minitech thank you for the suggestion,i remove the parseInt yet,and it's work,thank you.

Comment: @RogerWu - One thing that makes jQuery so cool is that you never need to put `"px"` or `number` into `css()`!

Comment: @Derek hahaha,ok,i got it,thank you very much and i'll always remember this sentence~

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` to make your code run repeatedly, then use `clearInterval` to stop the animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;

    $("#up_btn").hover(function() {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $("#move_box").css('top', '+= 1');
        }, 100); // Change the interval as you see fit.
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

Comment: one more question,is that no idea to use a event to listen the hover and let it always work?

Comment: @RogerWu: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "always work". Could you please rephrase?

Comment: sorry...i want to use a mouse event like "hover" or "mouseover" to judge whether to run the function or not,it will judge all the time,not once time...can you understand what i did say...

Comment: ok...you don't understand my mean...haha,forget it,maybe one day i can express it clearly then i will ask you again...haha,thank you for your help~:)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. For example:

```
var move_box_interval;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#up_btn").hover(function() {
        // Change the interval to be appropriate. It's in milliseconds.
        move_box_interval = setInterval(move_box, 100);
    });

    // Change this to the appropriate trigger.
    $("#up_btn").mouseout(function() {
        clearInterval(move_box_interval);
    });
});

function move_box() {
    $("#move_box").css("top", "+= 1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#up_btn").mouseenter(function() {
        var new_num = parseInt($("#move_box").css("top"));
        $("#move_box").css("top", new_num + 1);
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you,but this only run once time...maybe it's not work...but thank you all the same